# Magento system.xml cache issue

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I have been building a module and making numerous changes without any problems until just now:

I removed a configuration variable from my extension's system.xml file but the field is still in the config. I disabled all caching, flushed all caches (both through magento admin and by manually deleting everything in the directories) but it STILL won't go away.

As a test, I added it back to the system.xml file using the same node name but changing the label and it picked up the change.  I was also able to hide it by setting `<show_in_...>` to 0.  However, after it went away, I removed it from the system.xml file and it showed up again in the admin.  I have to imagine this is a caching issue but I can't figure out what to flush to make it go away.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things to check.  When you save a configuration value, magento (currently) persists it to the `core_config_data` table. Even if you remove the configuration field from your `system.xml` config. that path/value pair will still be stores in this database.  Do a

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = '/foo/baz/bar'
```

To see if there's still a values in there. If it is, calls to `Mage::getStoreConfig` will still return a value, again regardless of what's in `system.xml`

Secondly, Magento allows you to stores a default value for each configuration path in **`config.xml`**.   Look under the

```
<default>
   <foo>
       <baz>
           <bar>1</bar>
       </baz>
   </foo>
</default>
```

node for a nested tree path that matches your configuration path.  If this node is present then this value will be returned for requests to `Mage::getStoreConfig`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify.  I am aware of where it stores the values...that's not the issue.  I know that if I remove it from my extension's config and then ask for the getStoreConfig for that value, I'll get it.  That's fine.  The problem is that when I removed it from the system.xml for my extension, the field didn't go away when I view my extension config in the admin.  I deleted the entry in the `core_config_data` table and the field blanked out in the config for the extension, but the field itself won't go away.  It didn't do this on our live site either....weird...

Comment: You're not editing the file you think you're editing, or another module also has the field configured.  Failing that, trace the loading of system.xml in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/System.php.  Magento thinks you have a node there.  You need to figure out why.

Comment: Thanks for the direction.  I eventually found it.  Somehow (and I'm going to chalk this up to mischievous internet fairies), that extension's `system.xml` got copied into another extension's etc directory.  I'm probably to blame, but that certainly wasn't intentional.  Anyhow, mystery solved :)

Answer (score 1):

system.xml values are stored in the db, `core_config_data`: have you delete it there?

Comment: Yes, I did (see comment to Alan's answer).  The stored value went away, but the field itself is still there....so weird....